# Twilio paste UX Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I am trying to use Paste UX dropdown style(https://paste.twilio.design/components/select/) in my project but for some reason I am unable to.
Below is my code

```html
import React from "react";
import { withTaskContext } from "@twilio/flex-ui";
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import packageJson from "./../../package.json";
import {
  Box,
  Text,
  Anchor,
  FormLabel,
  FormInput,
  FormTextArea,
  Select,
  Option,
  Radio,
  RadioGroup,
  Checkbox,
  CheckboxGroup,
} from "@twilio-paste/core";
import paste from "@twilio-paste/core";

class VoiceCallComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      calldisposition: "1"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Box marginBottom="space50">
        <FormLabel htmlFor={inputID("select")}>Alert type</FormLabel>
        <Select
          id={inputID("select")}
          value={this.state.calldisposition}
           onChange={(event) => {
                this.setState({ calldisposition: event.target.value });
                this.props.task.attributes.calldisposition = event.target.value;
                this.props.task.setAttributes(this.props.task.attributes);
              }}
        >
          <Option value="">Select an option</Option>
          <Option value="1">Type 1</Option>
          <Option value="2">Option 2</Option>
          <Option value="3">Option 3</Option>
        </Select>
       </Box>
        );
  }
 }
```

I am expecting it to look like this
[image]

But instead I am getting this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was experiencing the same issue. The answer: Use a theme provider. See here: https://paste.twilio.design/introduction/for-engineers/manual-installation#setting-up-the-theme-provider

If you're using a flex plugin like me: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/use-paste-with-a-plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).